# PHP - Convert all POST data into SESSION variables

Tags: php, post, session-variables

There's got to be a much more elegant way of doing this.

How do I convert all non-empty post data to session variables, without specifying each one line by line? Basically, I want to perform the function below for all instances of X that exist in the POST array.

```
if (!empty($_POST['X'])) $_SESSION['X']=$_POST['X'];
```

I was going to do it one by one, but then I figured there must be a much more elegant solution

Comment: this is not a smart thing to do, use a predefined list you want to use for security

Answer (score 10):

I would specify a dictionary of POST names that are acceptable.

```
$accepted = array('foo', 'bar', 'baz');

foreach ( $_POST as $foo=>$bar ) {
    if ( in_array( $foo, $accepted ) && !empty($bar) ) {
        $_SESSION[$foo] = $bar;
    }
}
```

Or something to that effect. I would not use `empty` because it treats `0` as empty.

Comment: I am fine with 0 being treated as empty, in fact it would help to clean up my data. Thanks!

Comment: modified to fit your needs then.

Comment: To be honest, you should avoid using empty() at all - kick the habit now, and you'll develop techniques that will work in EVERY situation, not just this one. There are appropriate functions for every data type. Use them!

Comment: @mederomuraliev My Post method working good, https://snag.gy/ojWxHe.jpg   how can i use my session values and display in my table : https://www.pastiebin.com/5d25bbd65405e

Answer (score 3):

The syntax error, is just because there is a bracket still open. it should be

```
$vars = array('name', 'age', 'location');
foreach ($vars as $v) {
   if (isset($_POST[$v])) {
      $_SESSION[$v] = $_POST[$v];
   }
}
```

It should work like that. If you use

```
if ($_POST[$v])...
```

it strips down empty data.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go,

```
if(isset($_POST) {
 foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {
  if($val != "Submit")
   $_SESSION["$key"] = $val;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well the first thing I would suggest is you **don't** do this. It's a huge potential security hole. Let's say you rely on a session variable of username and/or usertype (very common). Someone can just post over those details. You should be taking a white list approach by only copying approved values from `$_POST` to `$_SESSION` ie:

```
$vars = array('name', 'age', 'location');
foreach ($vars as $v) {
  if (isset($_POST[$v]) {
    $_SESSION[$v] = $_POST[$v];
  }
}
```

How you define "empty" determines what kind of check you do. The above code uses `isset()`. You could also do `if ($_POST[$v]) ...` if you don't want to write empty strings or the number 0.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the pointer. So I would have to, in effect, do it one by one, but I can whitelist it in an array to keep the code tidy.

How do I implement a "not empty()" check into your code above, to ensure that only not-empty POST data get converted to session variables, even if it's in the whitelist? I am fine with "0" being registered as empty.

Answer (score 1):

This lead me to this bit, which is a simplified version of @meder's answer:

```
<?php
$accepted = array('foo', 'bar', 'baz');

foreach ( $accepted as $name ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST[$name] ) ) {
        $_SESSION[$name] = $_POST[$name];
    }
}
```

You might also substitute `!empty()` for `isset()` above, though be aware of how much farther-reaching `empty()` is, as @meder pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $_SESSION["data"] = $POST;
  $var = $_SESSION["data"];
```

Then just use $var as a post variable. For example:

```
  echo $var["email"];
```

instead of

```
  echo $_POST["email"];
```

Cheers